# What design pattern fits this case better

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, abstract

I am to produce a 2D image from a 3D model and do some calculation on the image and produce some results from that. Results will be attached at the top of that 2D image as its header.

- There are three different types of image which could be produced from a specific scene based on a parameter(DiagramType).
- Also an image can be created via two different ways: Ray tracing or through GPU. So the method 'CreateImage' which is responsible to produce the image could have two different signatures (different number of inputs).
- There are some methods which are common between these different types of diagram or rendering methods.

What design pattern dose fit this case better?

Would it be better to use abstract class (since there are some common methods which could be inherited) regarding those three diagram types or an Interface?

I am mostly concerned with this 'CreateImage' method which can have different signature regarding the method that is used, Such that each digram type would have one 'CreateImage' method regardless of diagram type and rendering method.(Im not sure this would be possible at all).

Comment: Curious - why have you identified the need for a design pattern to solve your problem?

Comment: I think since these three diagram types have one method for creating image but each can have its own implementation(besides this problem that the 'CreateImage' method also depends on another factor: Rendering type). And also there are some common operations which are shared among them.

Comment: Design patterns are not a silver bullet which instantly give you deeper insight into good design. I always cringe when I see questions on stack overflow that say "what design pattern should I use". The best advice I have for you is not to try to shoe-horn a design pattern into your design. Patterns are not solutions in and of themselves.

Comment: Then I would end up by implementing too many switch case or else if statements to choose which object to create or which method to use. Also there would be duplicated codes in different classes.

Comment: ahh, so you're seeking a design pattern to compensate for poor OO design. Perhaps the best thing to do would be to write the code as best you can - with *"too many switch case or else if statements"* and then post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You'll learn much more that way :)

Answer (score 0):

"Three different xxx vs two different yyy" which depend on each other sounds immediately like the Bridge Pattern to me.

In other words, you have a hierarchy of xxx, a hierarchy of yyy and xxx accepts injected yyy.